# Convert Varchar with Exponent to Decimal Data type

Tags: sql, sybase

I have column Amount with 10,000 records and its look like this.

```
1.24E4

27.27E1

3.25E2
```

and etc.

Now I need to update the column to make this result

```
12400

272.7

325
```

I need to know how to convert and update the column from varchar to decimal.

Take note that my Column `Amount` is in Varchar Data type.

Answer (score 0):

```
select convert(float, '1.24E4')
select convert(float, '27.27E1')
select convert(float, '3.25E2')
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply update with a cast to FLOAT:

```
UPDATE YOUR_TABLE
SET YOUR_COLUMN = CAST(YOUR_COLUMN AS FLOAT)
WHERE....your condition if there
```

Comment: but will the result is accurate if I cast it into float??

Comment: Yes result will be accurate, you can also cast to INT , but as you want to maintain some decimal points so FLOAT is best. If you have doubt then you can update only 1 record with where condition  and see effect. if all good then you can update all.